# simple pendulum equation, why it cannot be solved with laplace transform (the general solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Usually to solve the simple pendulum equation:
$\qquad \ell {\ddot  \theta }+g\sin \theta =0\,$

Using the first term of Taylor series is used as approximation, but although $\sin \theta$ can be transformed to Laplace "space" and use it to find a general solution, I can't find it.

Why there is no general solution in Laplace?

Comment: Wow, this week i was wondering the same thing. Hope some scholar could answer it!

Comment: Could you explain how exactly you would transform $\sin\theta$ to Laplace space, please?

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia article [Pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)) interesting.

Comment: You might be able to convert it to an integral equation or infinite-order differential equation in Laplace space, but I don't think that's all that helpful.

Comment: @wasn'tme From Table of Laplace Transforms: $sin(at)=\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$ although its calculation is not that hard using Euler's formula for sin().

Comment: But you don't have $\sin(at)$ in your equation, you have $\sin\theta$ with the unknown function $\theta=\theta(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Laplace transform can be helpful in solving linear differential equations.  But this one is nonlinear.